# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Law's [second moderator election](https://law.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: Dale M] [image: Pat W.]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://law.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking jimsug who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5955166291361792/0).